# The current type, "IAdmissionRepository," is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Tags: c#, interface, repository-pattern

I am new to repository pattern and trying to implement that in my project.
I am having entity class Admission.cs

```
   public class Admission
{
    public long AccountID { get; set; }
    public long ClientID { get; set; }
    public long AdmissionID { get; set; }
}
```

Then i am having interface like this:

```
namespace Common.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAdmissionLogic:IDisposable
    {
        Admission GetAdmission(long admissionId);
        void UpdateAdmission(Admission admission);
    }
}
```

Then i am having business logic class in different project as:

```
 public class AdmissionLogic:IAdmissionLogic
    {
        private IAdmissionRepository data;

        public AdmissionLogic()
        {
            var dependencyContainer = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
            dependencyContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IAdmissionLogic));
            data = dependencyContainer.Resolve<IAdmissionRepository>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            data.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Then i am having interface in data project as:

```
namespace Data.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAdmissionRepository:IDisposable
    {
        CommonEntities.Admission GetAdmission(long admissionId);
        void UpdateAdmission(CommonEntities.Admission admission);
    }
}
```

Then i am having actual repository class in same project as above one as:

```
namespace Data.Repositories
{
    public class AdmissionRepository : EntitiesRepositoryBase<Data.Admission, CommonEntities.Admission>, IAdmissionRepository
    {
        public CommonEntities.Admission GetAdmission(long admissionId)
        {

        }
}
}
```

When i write the following line in actual aspx page where i am querying;

```
 AdmissionLogic admissionLogic = new AdmissionLogic();
 Admission admission = admissionLogic.GetAdmission(AdmissionId);
```

I am getting in AdmissionLogic as :
The current type, "IAdmissionRepository," is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know much about Unity container but I'm pretty sure you have to register the the abstract type, ie interface with the actual implementing type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registration part does not seem to be correct. You are registering the `IAdmissionLogic` but without an implementation. Then you never resolve an `IAdmissionLogic` component, but an `IAdmissionRepository`. 
You should instead register the Repository with its implementing type.

```
dependencyContainer.RegisterType<IAdmissionRepository, AdmissionRepository>();
```

Also your registration code should go to the composition root (once per application) and not in a class implementing business logic. See http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/ for an explanation.

Comment: This worked fine, i came to know that i am registering IAdmissionLogic which is wrong. I should be registering IAdmissionRepository. Then it worked fine. Also, i am  having unity.config file which is doing this mapping but it did not do that for me because i am having another repository with same name in other  project and it is finding that instead of new one. Then i changed unity.config file with fully qualified namespace to IAdmissionRepository. This cleared all errors and worked perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencyContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IAdmissionLogic));
```

There are likely two issues here.

a) You should be registering the [concrete type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507499(v=pandp.30).aspx#registertype_mapping) (i.e. class), not the interface.

b) You shouldn't be doing this in the constructor of `AdmissionLogic` (otherwise it will run many times).

*Your `dependencyContainer` should be being created (and assigned to a `static` variable) once at startup. Registrations should be setup at the same time (once, not repeatedly).*